# How to traverse an AST generated by a 3rd party parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an [AST](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/e74ee7c447548afb12989ab2610ee020) generated by a [3rd party parser](https://github.com/ConsenSys/solidity-parser), which I cannot change. How to walk/traverse through it using Javascript, or even better using TypeScript?

Comment: It doesn't matter what parser generated it. The only thing of importance is the format of the tree. Does it comply with any AST standard?

Comment: "*How to walk/traverse through it*" - just loop and recurse? What exactly do you want to do with the tree? Do you want to run existing tooling (babel, tsc) on it?

Comment: No, it is customized and does not comply with any known AST standard. I want to walk thru it and generate more info for further processing such as type checking. Wanna see if there is some library/tool to do it without manual looping and recursing.

Comment: Tbh, it does look a lot like [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree) though, possibly with custom extensions like a `Contract` type.

Comment: What exactly do you expect your "walk" to look like, what should the "further processing" do? There is not much such a library would do other than looping and recursing, and it's unclear what kind of abstraction from that you imagine.

Comment: Sth like this:
`walk(ast, {
    enter: function (node) {
        // do sth
    }
});`

Comment: Have you tried [estree-walker](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/estree-walker#why-not-use-estraverse) (among the first google hits)?

Comment: estree-walker only works for ESTree-compliant AST, which does not apply to my AST.

Comment: How exactly is your ast not estree-compliant, and how does using estree-walker fail on your input? Btw, the docs say that it works on any estree-compliant ast, not that it works *only* on estree-compliant asts.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the format of the [result](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/e74ee7c447548afb12989ab2610ee020#file-ast-json) you shared, we know the tree is made of nodes that might contain nodes inside, and that every node is an object with a field `type` and other fields (which other fields depend on the `type` too).

My approach would be to "traverse" this tree by a function that receives a node and selects which function to call depending on `type`.

e.g.

```js
function visitProgram(node) {
    // do something with program node
    // call visitNode to it's children too
}

function visitFuncDecl(node) {
    // similar to visitProgram
    console.log(node.name)
}

function visitNode(node) {
    const type = node.type;
    switch(type) {
        case "Program":
            visitProgram(node);
        break;
        case "FunctionDeclaration":
            visitFuncDecl(node):
        break;
        // ... and so on with the rest of the node types
        default:
            throw `unexpected node type: ${node.type}`
        break;
    }
}
```

Although this approach would get unwieldy pretty fast, It depends on what you want to do with it. As pointed by comments, using an already existing tool might be better.

Comment: Essentially, I am asking if there is any existing tool to walk AST. There are tools for traversing standard AST like [antlr](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeWalker.html). But not sure such tools exist for generic ASTs.